# How do I use PROC EXPAND to fill in time series observations within a panel (longitudinal) data set?

Tags: sas

I'm using this SAS code:

```
data test1;
    input cust_id $
          month
          category $
          status $;
datalines;
A 200003 ABC C
A 200004 DEF C
A 200006 XYZ 3
B 199910 ASD X
B 199912 ASD C
;
quit;

proc sql;
    create view test2 as
        select cust_id, input(put(month, 6.), yymmn6.) as month format date9., 
               category, status from test1 order by cust_id, month asc;
quit;

proc expand data=test2 out=test3 to=month method=none;
    by cust_id;
    id month;
quit;

proc print data=test3;
    title "after expand";
quit;
```

and I want to create a dataset that looks like this:

```
Obs cust_id month category status 
1 A 01MAR2000 ABC C 
2 A 01APR2000 DEF C
3 A 01MAY2000 .   .  
4 A 01JUN2000 XYZ 3 
5 B 01OCT1999 ASD X 
6 B 01NOV1999 .   .
7 B 01DEC1999 ASD C
```

but the output from `proc expand` just says "Nothing to do. The data set WORK.TEST3 has 0 observations and 0 variables." I don't want/need to change the frequency of the data, just interpolate it with missing values.

What am I doing wrong here? I think `proc expand` is the correct procedure to use, based on [this example](http://support.sas.com/kb/22/921.html) and the [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/60372/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_expand_sect016.htm), but for whatever reason it doesn't create the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `VAR` statement.  Unfortunately, the variables need to be numeric.  So just expand the `month` by `cust_id`.  Then join back the original values.

```
proc expand data=test2 out=test3 to=month ;
    by cust_id;
    id month;
    var _numeric_;
quit;

proc sql noprint;
create table test4 as
select a.*,
       b.category,
       b.status
    from test3 as a
      left join
         test2 as b
    on a.cust_id = b.cust_id
     and a.month = b.month;
quit;

proc print data=test4;
    title "after expand";
quit;
```